# Partial derivative for a composite function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuously differentiable functions. I'm interested in the partial derivative of $f(g(x),x)$ with respect to the second element. By definition, the partial of $f$ with respect to the second element evaluated at $(g(x),x)$ is
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{f(g(x),x+\varepsilon)-f(g(x),x)}{\varepsilon}= (\partial_2f)_{(g(x),x)}.
$$

But, I was wondering if
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\frac{f(g(x+\varepsilon),x+\varepsilon)-f(g(x+\varepsilon),x)}{\varepsilon}=(\partial_2f)_{(g(x),x)}
$$
is true or not. Note that the second term in the denominator is $f(g(x+\varepsilon),x)$, not $f(g(x),x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fully Edited:**

The first equation you have is true simply by definition of the partial derivative. The second equation is also true because of how your numerator is written, though this time the proof is not so trivial. A simple proof would be to just invoke the definition of differentiability and the chain rule.

Let us fix an $x\in\Bbb{R}$ and define two functions $\Phi,\Psi:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, as
\begin{align}
\Phi(\epsilon):=f(g(x+\epsilon),x+\epsilon),\quad\text{and}\quad
\Psi(\epsilon):=f(g(x+\epsilon),x).
\end{align}
Notice in particular that
\begin{align}
\Phi(0)=\Psi(0)=f(g(x),x).\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
Now, the limit you're asking about in the second equation is
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\Phi(\epsilon)-\Psi(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}&=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\Phi(\epsilon)-\Phi(0)}{\epsilon}-
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\Psi(\epsilon)-\Psi(0)}{\epsilon}\tag{by $*$}\\
&=\Phi'(0)-\Psi'(0)\\
&=\left[(\partial_1f)_{(g(x),x)}\cdot g'(x)+
(\partial_2f)_{(g(x),x)}\right]-\left[(\partial_1f)_{(g(x),x)}\cdot 
g'(x)+0\right]\tag{chain rule}\\
&=(\partial_2f)_{(g(x),x)}.
\end{align}

The intuitive reason for why you still get the same result in the second case is that you're doing $f(g(x+\epsilon),x+\epsilon)-f(g(x+\epsilon),x)$, and since the argument of $f$ in the first slot stays the same, this doesn't contribute in this first order change. Even if you had something more complicated, such as
\begin{align}
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{f(G(x,\epsilon),x+\epsilon)-f(G(x,\epsilon),x)}{\epsilon},
\end{align}
where $G:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}$, the answer would still be $(\partial_2f)_{(G(x,0),x)}$.

Comment: I edited the question so that it is less confusing. My question is if the partial of $f$ with respect the second element evaluated at $(g(x),x)$ can be written as the limit as in the second equation.

Comment: I do not see the limit in my second equation in the equations that you wrote out, so I'm still not sure how to say my second equation is incorrect...

Comment: @user789100 oh my apologies, I read the numerator incorrectly despite your warning in the final sentence, I'll edit soon

Comment: @user789100 let me know if the explanation is clearer this time around